# need help randomizing numbers in a memory game

Tags: java, swing, memory

This creates a jframe with 3 rows and 4 columns. Im trying to achieve a memory game where it matches the letters. As of now the code matches, but the letters aren't randomly placed. I couldn't find anything about this online. I would also like to know if their is a method that i can use to change the background of the GUI.

```
public class matchinggame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel p;
    JFrame f;
    String[][] matchList = { {"a", "a"}, {"b", "b"},
            {"c", "c" }, {"d", "d"}, {"e", "e"},
            {"f", "f"}, {"g", "g" }};
    JButton[][] buttons;
    int i = 0;
    boolean flipping = true;
    int cardOne;
    int secIndex;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread
        //to create application and display its GUI
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                matchinggame app = new matchinggame();
                app.makeGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void dealCards(JPanel panel) {
        buttons = new JButton[3][]; // array of buttons used to represent cards
        for (int i= 0; i< 3*4; i++) { // initialize 3 rows with 4 columns each
            if (i%4 == 0) buttons[i/4] = new JButton[4];
            buttons[i/4][i%4] = new JButton("-Match-"); // show face down
            buttons[i/4][i%4].addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(buttons[i/4][i%4]);
        }
    }

    public void updateMatchList(String a, String b, boolean add) {
        int i,j;
        String[][] courseList;
        int oldLen = matchList.length;

        if (add) { // add the new item to the list
            courseList = new String[oldLen+1][];
            courseList[0] = new String[2];
            courseList[0][0] = new String(a); // new first course
            courseList[0][1] = new String(b); // new first course num
            for (int item=1; item<= oldLen; item++) {
                courseList[item][0] = matchList[item-1][0];
                courseList[item][1] = matchList[item-1][1];
            }
            matchList = courseList;
        } else { // delete matching item
            courseList = new String[oldLen-1][];
            courseList[0] = new String[2];
            courseList[0][0] = new String(a); // new first course
            courseList[0][1] = new String(b); // new first course num
            for (int item=0; item<= oldLen; item++) {
                if (a != courseList[item][0]) { // no match so OK to copy over
                    courseList[item][0] = matchList[item][0];
                    courseList[item][1] = matchList[item][1];
                }
            }
            matchList = courseList;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the JFrame and its UI components.
     */
    public  void makeGUI() {    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CS435F08 - Java Match Game Starter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,4));
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        dealCards(p);    
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int r,c;


        if (i<2) { //find the card clicked on and flip it over

            for (r=0; r< 3; r++) {
                for (c=0; c< 4; c++) {
                    // if the card is not face down (showing "-Match-") don't flip it
                    if ((e.getSource()== buttons[r][c]) && buttons[r][c].getText().equals("-Match-")){
                        // flip the card face-up to show text from matchList
                        // looks up text based upon indexes
                        buttons[r][c].setText(matchList[(r*4+c)/2][(r*4+c)%2]);
                        i++; // increment number of cards flipped
                        if (i==1) cardOne = (r*4+c)/2; // save which pattern was shown first
                        else secIndex = (r*4+c)/2; // save the pattern shown second
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else { // 2 cards already flipped, put all cards face down

            for (r=0; r< 3; r++) {
                for (c=0; c< 4; c++) {
                    if (cardOne == secIndex) { // first and second cards flipped match
                        if (!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("-Match-")) // don't change the face down cards
                            buttons[r][c].setText("*******"); // once matched, show the removed pattern
                    } else if ((!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("*******")) && (!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("-Match-"))) {
                        buttons[r][c].setText("-Match-"); // if 2 face up cards didn't match, flip face down again
                    }
                }
                i=0; // new turn, no cards flipped face up
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the matchList to a 1 dimensional array.  This way, I could shuffle the text in the shuffleCards method.

Here's the GUI.

[image: Match Game GUI]

I fixed some problems with your action listener.

Here's the formatted code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MatchingGame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel p;
    JFrame f;

    String[] matchList = { "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e",
            "f", "f", "g", "g" };
    String[] shuffledList;

    JButton[][] buttons;

    boolean flipping = true;

    int i = 0;
    int cardOne;
    int secIndex;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread
        // to create application and display its GUI
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MatchingGame app = new MatchingGame();
                app.makeGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void dealCards(JPanel panel) {
        buttons = new JButton[3][]; // array of buttons used to represent cards
        shuffleCards();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 4; i++) { // initialize 3 rows with 4 columns
                                            // each
            if (i % 4 == 0)
                buttons[i / 4] = new JButton[4];
            buttons[i / 4][i % 4] = new JButton("-Match-"); // show face down
            buttons[i / 4][i % 4].addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(buttons[i / 4][i % 4]);
        }
    }

    public void shuffleCards() {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(matchList);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        shuffledList = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }

    public void updateMatchList(String a, String b, boolean add) {
        String[] courseList;
        int oldLen = matchList.length;

        if (add) { // add the new item to the list
            courseList = new String[oldLen + 2];
            courseList[0] = new String(a); // new first course
            courseList[1] = new String(b); // new first course num
            for (int item = 2; item <= oldLen; item += 2) {
                courseList[item] = matchList[item - 2];
                courseList[item + 1] = matchList[item - 1];
            }
            matchList = courseList;
        } else { // delete matching item
            courseList = new String[oldLen - 2];
            int matchItem = 0;
            for (int item = 0; item <= oldLen; item += 2) {
                if (a != matchList[item]) { // no match so OK to copy over
                    courseList[item] = matchList[matchItem];
                    courseList[item + 1] = matchList[matchItem + 1];
                    matchItem += 2;
                }
            }
            matchList = courseList;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Creates the JFrame and its UI components.
     */
    public void makeGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CS435F08 - Java Match Game Starter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 4));
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        dealCards(p);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int r, c;

        if (i < 2) { // find the card clicked on and flip it over

            for (r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                    // if the card is not face down (showing "-Match-") don't
                    // flip it
                    if ((e.getSource() == buttons[r][c])
                            && buttons[r][c].getText().equals("-Match-")) {
                        // flip the card face-up to show text from matchList
                        // looks up text based upon indexes
                        buttons[r][c].setText(shuffledList[(r * 4 + c)]);
                        i++; // increment number of cards flipped
                        if (i == 1)
                            cardOne = (r * 4 + c); // save which pattern was
                                                    // shown first
                        else
                            secIndex = (r * 4 + c); // save the pattern
                                                    // shown second
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else { // 2 cards already flipped, put all cards face down

            for (r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
                for (c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                    // first and second cards flipped
                    if (shuffledList[cardOne].equals(shuffledList[secIndex])) {
                        // match
                        // don't change the face down cards
                        if (!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("-Match-"))
                            // once matched, show the removed pattern
                            buttons[r][c].setText("*******");
                    } else if ((!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("*******"))
                            && (!buttons[r][c].getText().equals("-Match-"))) {
                        // if 2 face up cards didn't match, flip face down again
                        buttons[r][c].setText("-Match-");
                    }
                }
                i = 0; // new turn, no cards flipped face up
            }
        }
    }
}
```